# Is the word "well-improved" correct?

Tags: grammar

> Transportation facilities are **well-improved**.

Is this a correct sentence?

I don't know if the word **well-improved** can be used in this sentence.

Comment: It works fine. But note that no hyphen is needed between an adverb and an adjective.

Answer (score 1):

If something can be improved, it can be improved to a degree, and it stands to reason that it can be "well improved" as well.

That said, it sounds a bit awkward to use that formulation in English, except perhaps in specific circumstances where the verb *improve* had already been established and probably repeated. In most cases you can get by simply with *improved*. To advance beyond that degree you might have to say the thing had been "greatly improved" (or similar) to sound natural.

Comment: I agree that "greatly improved" is more common and sounds more natural, though I don't think "well improved" sounds wrong at all. I'm not so sure about the "circumstances where the verb improve had already been established and probably repeated" part. If something were improved only once yet improved beyond my expectations, I would consider it "well improved". In fact, I would say that, in common usage, "improved" by itself is often followed by "but" and thus may not carry the connotation that "well improved" does.